# Trying to make a background color block reach the top and bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have a background image on my page, I'm trying to place a color block that goes behind all my content but leaves the background image visible in the margins.

How do I get it to reach the top and bottom of the page?

I've placed a `<div>` tag around all my content excepting the logo image in the corner like so (please let me know if anything is unclear):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Services</title>
<link href="Coppermug Stylesheet Services.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <div>
        <a class="home-logo" href="EXAMPLE.html"><img src="EXAMPLE" id=bannerlogo></a>
     </div>

    <div class="white-background">
    <div class="navbar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link" href="EXAMPLE.html">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="EXAMPLE.html">Services</a>
</li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="EXAMPLE.html">About Us</a>
          </li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="EXAMPLE.html">Contact</a>
</li>
   </div>
</div>


html {
    background-image: url("../Final Logo Assets/Minimized/Blur Mug-min Opacity-min.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}   


.white-background {
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: As @Andrei Sandica mentioned, you shouldn't really style the very base of your webpage. You can create a `div` right next to the html and do the same styling you wish. Now for the full width and height, try setting your `body` like: `{margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't exactly get what you are trying to do, but in the most cases, if you want something to extend from top to bottom of the page, you could try `height: 100%` or `height: 100vh`, vh refers to viewport height and takes 100% of your screen height.

Also, it is kind of a bad practice to use a background image to the html tag, I'd suggest you to use a wrapper div and use the background on that div.

And if you're going to use the 100vh, use the calc function of css but you have to subtract the height of the navbar.

Example : 
If your navbar is 50px, you have to use `height: calc(100vh - 50px)`

Answer (score 0):

1.) You need to use `height: 100%;` for the element itself AND for all its parent elements in order to have a height reference for the percentage.

2.) Add `margin: 0` to `body` and `html` to avoid the default margin.

3.) Add a tiny (1px)  top and `margin-bottom` to you `.white-background` element in order to avoid collapsing margins of its children elements to cause a margin at its top and bottom

4.) I suppose your logo has absolute position - if not, add it.

```css
html {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/800x1200/fa0");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.white-background {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1px 0;
}

.home-logo {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="home-logo" href="EXAMPLE.html"><img src="https://placehold.it/100x30/af0" id=bannerlogo></a>
</div>

<div class="white-background">
  <div class="navbar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="EXAMPLE.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="EXAMPLE.html">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="EXAMPLE.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="EXAMPLE.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML and Body tags are the sizes of the content inside them in some browsers in others they are the viewport size but you can override the default CSS rules applied.
The easiest way to combat this is to set your `<html>` tag to the viewport size.

CSS:

```
html{
   postion:absolute;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   right:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   overflow:auto;
   background:blue; /* this would be your background setup */
}
```